Windows WSL1: How to disable all sounds?
WSL1 @ Windows 10:
How to disable all sounds / mute a WSL instance ? (for one or all distributions)
I could not find any reasonable guide to setup WSL desktop.
So stock gnome-control-center cannot launch.
(This question specifically asks for solution on WSL1, not for WSL2 or other virtual machines)

For sounds generated in Bash:
cat >> ~/.inputrc # (to append to the file) then type the following line:
set bell-style none
hold CTRL hit D,
finally, do bind -f ~/.inputrc once to load it.
(You may need to check that the line isn't present twice or more)
